# is JPEG artifact in any case unavoidable when increasing image size?

Tags: windows, ssd, pdf, compression, imagemagick

When I increase the image size to 200% or higher , the JPEG artifacts (ugly dots around sharp edges) are clearly visible. Same goes for PDF files that are lossily compressed.

Are there no compression methods/software/workarounds that help achieving small file size and good quality of the images?

I tried MRC(or Mixed Raster Content) compression algorithms after reading some rave reviews But it only made the quality worse, far from improving. it made the image very blurry and added more smudges.

with lossless compression, there's no worry about quality but file size remains large, bad for the storage.

I tried almost all compression software and online tools But nothing gave me one bit of satisfaction.

Any new ideas?

Comment: I edited your question to focus it. "Zooming" is what you do on an image viewer, and you seem to be talking about increasing the actual image size. If I'm in error, please feel free to correct the edit.

Comment: Storage is cheap. Discarded information in lossy formats is gone forever. Your call. A lot of my master images are easily 150MB or more; the versions that go online can be tiny, but nothing lost, masters still safe.

Comment: What comes to jpg artifacts increasing file size: assume an image 100x100px. You have exactly 10 000 pixels; i.e. units of information forming the image. An image of 150x150px has 22 500 pixels. Increasing the image size this way means you have to find somewhere 12 500 units of information which simply aren't present in the original data - that's what causes the artifacts. There are (expensive) tools that can pretty accurately re-create the missing info using algorithms, but it's still a guesstimation so somewhat inaccurate; and the larger the increase, the larger the inaccuracies become.

Comment: You could argue image quality = data. The more data, the better quality. Wanting small amount of data (small file) AND good quality is wanting the impossible. This requirement of yours will guarantee lack of 'one bit of satisfaction' by definition.

Answer (score 2):

JPEG-artifacts are the byproduct of the JPEG compression process which is triggered when saving into JPEG-type file.
You can avoid JPEG-artifacts by using "JPEG lossless" as setting for that process but it comes at the price of increased storage need.

If your source file is already containing JPEG artifacts because the JPEG compression process had been triggered sometimes earlier, you cannot get rid of the artifacts without manipulating the picture. The information loss due to JPEG compression cannot be reversed. The use of a lossless image format can only assure that your image bitmap stays the same.

Comment: Yes, JPEG employs *two* compression methods, one being lossy (by simply reducing amount of data or information -> loss of quality) and lossless (Huffman, similar to how zipping a file works, so 'compacting' information). As you say, the lost information is lost forever. One could argue some form of AI could enhance the image, but only by adding *new* information that the algorithm essentially makes up.